# How to copy a table but randomise the rows with respect to one of the columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know how can I mix up the data order while insert the records into another table in SQL?

Example:
I have 2 tables, `Table A` and `Table B`, I would like to insert the record from `Table A` to `Table B`, how ever I would like the records mix up while insert into `Table B` insert of follow the order in Table A. Will it be possible to do it in SQL?

```
Table A:

ID     Postcode    Total
1      3000        10
2      3000        20
3      3000        5 
4      3001        10
5      3001        6
6      3002        6
7      3002        9
8      3002        10
9      3003        85
10     3004        1
```

After insert into `Table B` (the records randomly mixed up):

```
ID     Postcode    Total
1      3001        10
2      3002        20
3      3000        5 
4      3003        85
5      3002        6
6      3001        6
7      3002        9
8      3000        20
9      3000        10
10     3004        1
```

Comment: The order you insert data into a table is irrelevant except unless you are trying to randomly generate identities or improve batch loading performance. When you select back out of this table, the order the records come out is 100% reliable only on the `ORDER BY`. Do not expect data to be selected out in the same order that it was inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TableA ORDER BY NEWID()) AS tmp
```

Make sure TableB does not have a clustered key or else it won't work. Change `TOP 10` to the number of rows you have in TableA.

Edit: a commenter pointed that the original version won't work in SQL Server 2012 and above. In that case you need a more heavy handed version (updated).

Comment: This isn't actually what they are trying to do anyway. Should be clearer now with the formatting. The rows need to be randomised with respect to the id column.